# Select List item based on custom column using rest api

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api

I am trying to select List Items on a document Library where I was able to successfully do based on ID. But I am trying to see whether it is possible to filter based on custom column. Is it possible to query based on custom column?

This is working:

```
req.setEndpoint('callout:SPO_Integration/_api/web/lists/getbytitle(\'SalesforceDocuments\')/items(\'1\')/File');
```

The following option is not working:

```
req.setEndpoint('callout:SPO_Integration/_api/web/lists/getbytitle(\'SalesforceDocuments\')/items(\'510111329\')/File');
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To filter by a column other than ID, you need to use `$filter`, so your call should be something like

```
req.setEndpoint('callout:SPO_Integration/_api/web/lists/getbytitle(\'SalesforceDocuments\')/items'
    + '?filter=YourCustomField = \'YourCustomValue\'');
```

This will return an array of list items; if it is the File that you need, you will need to use `$expand=File` as well.

So in the end you should have

```
req.setEndpoint('callout:SPO_Integration/_api/web/lists/getbytitle(\'SalesforceDocuments\')/items'
    + '?filter=YourCustomField = \'YourCustomValue\'&$expand=File');
```

You may also want to look into using `$select` to limit your results to only those you require.